# jquery add/remove sortable divs and update count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am coding a photo upload section where divs can be added and removed at the click of a button(s). Which can be seen here -- [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8avoyfs/12/)

and I am trying to get the number counts working properly when a div is added, removed, or reordered.

So far it seems to increment the number when the div is added, but it doesnt update the number when reordered or other numbers when removed.

```
     // MOVE LEFT AND RIGHT FUNCTION
$( function() {
    $( "#pic-con" ).sortable();
    $( "#pic-con" ).disableSelection();
  });

$(document).on('click', '.pic-left', function (){
  var current = $(this).parents(':eq(1)');
  current.prev().before(current);

});
$(document).on('click', '.pic-right', function (){
  var current = $(this).parents(':eq(1)');
  current.next().after(current);
});

$(function(){
    var div = 0;

// ADD MORE FUNCTION
 $('.add_more').click(function(){
  div++;
   var numItems = $('div.photo-upload-box').length;
  $('#pic-con').append('<div class="photo-upload-box"><div class="photo-upload-img"><img src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/3386/1525211184-62491.png" /></div><div class="photo-upload-field"><input type="file" name="files" class="files" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg" /><input type="hidden" name="file1" /></div><div class="photo-upload-settings"><div class="pic-left"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div><div class="pic-right"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div><div class="pic-remove remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>div '+div+' out of '+numItems+'</div><div class="photo-custom-time" style="display:none"><label>Duration time: </label> <input type="text" /></div></div>');
    });

 // REMOVE FUNCTION
 $(document).on("click", ".remove", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents(':eq(1)').remove();
        var numItems = $('div.photo-upload-box').length;
});
 })();
```

Comment: I believe you want your `var numItems = ...` to be *inside* of your `$('.add_more')` click event. Right now it's not being touched. The only time you set it is on initialization, and it never gets updated. The one in your `remove` function is locally scoped and completely independent.

Comment: @TylerRoper ok I updated the fiddle. If you check it out by adding and removing things etc. you can see what I mean about the numbers.

Comment: Your fiddle does not show `numItems` inside of the `$('.add_more')` click event.

Comment: I updated it, im not sure why thats happening. I edited my code in my question though as well. @TylerRoper

Comment: Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/m8avoyfs/15/)?

Comment: @TylerRoper very close except when re-ordering them they do not update as should

Comment: You can use the function I wrote, `updateIndexes();`, to update them whenever you want.

Comment: @TylerRoper ok it seems as though got it working with your help. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @TylerRoper in your answer you have the numbers updating in a span tag... but how can i use a variable so that i can add it to my div id's such as - "picture-1", "picture-2" - and it function the same way as it does now with updating etc?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to update the total count in all divs, then your html need to have a class

```
<div>div '+div+' out of <span class="numItems"></span></div>
```

so you can update the number

in your add

```
 $('span.numItems').text(numItems+1);
```

in your remove

```
$('span.numItems').text(numItems);
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karthikeyan_shanmugavadivelan/tb2k0e15/)

Comment: I left out the part to update the index number correctly in all for you to do it on your own, but the idea is similar to what I did for updating the total count in all places. Likewise you can update the index in each photo box accordingly

Comment: seems to be on the right track except that when re-ordering or removing elements (and adding some again) the numbers get messed up.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, I only added the fix for total count. (adding,removing 0r re-ordering all updates the total count correctly) The increment number assigned for each photo& updating the number on re-ordering you can handle it using similar logic.